# OnPropertyChanged not triggered

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new in MVVM and I tried to retrieve from 2 textboxes an username and a password. But OnPropertyChanged is not triggered even if I have UpdateSourceTriggered=PropertyChanged. Here is the code. I also tried with an class RelayCommand which uses the delegates Action<> and Func<> but neither that worked.

LogInCommand.cs

```
using LibraryApp.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace LibraryApp.Commands
{
    public class LogInCommand : ICommand
    {
        private LogInViewModel _logInViewModel;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public LogInCommand(LogInViewModel logInViewModel)
        {
            _logInViewModel = logInViewModel;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _logInViewModel.CanUpdate;

        public void Execute(object parameter) => _logInViewModel.Execute();
    }
}
```

LogInModel.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace LibraryApp.Models
{
    public class LogInModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _strUsername;
        private string _strPassword;

        public string Username 
        {
            get { return _strUsername; }
            set {
                _strUsername = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(Username);
            }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get { return _strPassword; }
            set
            {
                _strPassword = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(Password);
            }
        }

        public LogInModel(string strUsername, string strPassword)
        {
            Username = strUsername;
            Password = strPassword;
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

LogInViewModel.cs

```
using LibraryApp.Commands;
using LibraryApp.Models;
using LibraryApp.Models.DatabaseModel;
using LibraryApp.Views;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace LibraryApp.ViewModels
{
    public class LogInViewModel 
    {
        private LogInModel _user;
        private LibraryEntities _database;

        public LogInModel User
        {
            get { return _user; }
        }
        public bool CanUpdate
        {
            get
            {
                if (User == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return !(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(User.Username) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(User.Password));
            }
        }

        public ICommand SubmitCommand { get; set; }

        public void Execute()
        {
            if (IsUserInDatabase())
            {
                UserPage userPage = new UserPage();
                userPage.Show();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or password are incorrect.");
            }
        }

        public LogInViewModel()
        {
            _user = new LogInModel("admin", "d7x2rt58");
            _database = new LibraryEntities();
            SubmitCommand = new LogInCommand(this);
        }

        public bool IsUserInDatabase()
        {
            if (_database.BookKeepers.First(it => it.Username == User.Username && it.Password == User.Password) != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

LogIn.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="LibraryApp.Views.LogIn"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LibraryApp.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="LogIn" Height="150" Width="300" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid Margin="5">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Log In" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Username"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Password"/>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LogInModel.Username, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LogInModel.Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" Content="Log In"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

LogIn.xaml.cs

```
using LibraryApp.ViewModels;
using System.Windows;

namespace LibraryApp.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for LogIn.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class LogIn : Window
    {
        public LogIn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LogInViewModel logInViewModel = new LogInViewModel();
            DataContext = logInViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

UserPage.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="LibraryApp.Views.UserPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LibraryApp.Views"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      Height="450" Width="800"
      Title="UserPage">

    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Welcome" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="52" Width="134" FontSize="30"/>
        <Button Content="Add book" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104,145,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Borrow book" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104,190,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Delete book" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104,242,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Add user" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="314,145,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Delete user" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="314,195,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="314,242,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="648,360,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

UserPage.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace LibraryApp.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserPage.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserPage : Window
    {
        public UserPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has nothing to do with the PropertyChanged of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. It only controls how the source property of a Binding is updated when the target property changes. You set it on the Text Binding of a TextBox to make sure that the source property is updated on each keystroke.

Comment: The two textBoxes are bound to the property `LogInViewModel.LogInModel` that does not exist, maybe you meant `LogInViewModel.User`. Anyway, I don't understand when do you expect the `PropertyChange` notification to be fired. If those fields are edited only via UI then you should be listenig to the event. Other way around it doesn't seem like you are editing the properties in the code.

Comment: Yes, indeed an istance of type `LogInViewModel` is the `DataContext` of the `Window` `LogIn`. But when you specify `Binding` path, it start searching form the `DataContext`. So having `{Binding LogInModel.Username, [ext...]` it means that it will search for a property named `LogInModel` inside the instance of type `LogInViewModel`, which does not exists.

Comment: @Federico You're right. The LogInModel property in the LogInViewModel instance in the LogIn's DataContext is named `User`. Hence the property paths should be `User.Username` and `User.Password`.

Comment: Thank you all, especially to @FedericoRossi, for the useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. First of all, try to limit the amount of code you post to just the parts that are necessary. People will quickly skip your question when you post a wall of text.

To answer your question...

In `LogInModel` in the setters of `Username` and `Password` you are raising the event by passing in the values of the properties and not the property names themselves:

```cs
public string Username 
{
    get { return _strUsername; }
    set
    {
        _strUsername = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(Username);
    }
}
```

Instead you should pass in the name of the property itself:

```cs
public string Username 
{
    get { return _strUsername; }
    set
    {
        _strUsername = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Username));
        // The above is the same as:
        // OnPropertyChanged("Username");
    }
}
```

Comment: While true, this is not the whole story. See the comments on the question.

Comment: And... the `OnPropertyChanged` could be => `protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
      {
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }` and doesn't require passing anything.

Comment: Thank you for observing that mistake. I would not see it very soon.

Comment: You can also use the OnPropertyChanged like `OnPropertyChanged("Username")`